# extra symbols in LaTeX \metre output

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'm new to the LaTeX `metre` package, but am hoping to use it to create a poetry handout. Right now, it is generating extra symbols when I export from `org-mode`.

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[en]{metre}
\metra{\m\b}
```

Produces:

[image]

The last two symbols there are the ones I asked for. How do I eliminate the four extraneous other symbols from this output?

Answer (score 1):

Remember when exporting to pdf, a latex file is generated which is then compiled to pdf.  You can always look at the generated tex file and try to tweak it.  Here, when exporting to pdf, the generated latex file looks ok, but compiling it, through producing a pdf, raises an error.  I tracked it down to the fact that `\usepackage{metre}` should appear *before* the `\usepackage{amsmath}` inserted by the exporter.  I'm not sure how to fix this in org (maybe with the variable `org-latex-packages-alist`) but fixing this in the latex file, while removing the error, does not change the output.

Actually, even when compiling the minimal latex file below, the output is still the same.  This does not seem to be a problem with emacs or org.  I would suggest asking on tex.stackexchange.com.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[en]{metre}
\begin{document}
\metra{\m\b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strangely, when I compile your example, I still end up with the extra symbols. However, for the time being I've found a workaround, which is that the "breve" and "macron" symbols are available through the `textcomp` package, and it doesn't produce these same strangenesses on my system. For my simple needs, it is sufficient. Thank you!

Comment: @StevenArntson I do also have the extra symbols, which is why I think the problem is not org-related.

Comment: Sorry---misunderstood you! Thank you.